# JSON object to listView

Tags: android, json, parsing, listview, object

i am newbie to android, I wanted to implement dynamically JSON data to my android listView, I have only to objects in JSON file this are dealname and discount.

I checked all questions and tutorials but when i implemented those codes in application, neither one is running. I just wanted to ask, to implement such JSON data, should i need to parse data and convert into String array so simple listview work, or i need to implement custom listview? 
Plz your suggestions will help to solve this assignment..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to parse the json data into simple array and then set that array to adapter.

Comment: more see this tutorial http://mobile.dzone.com/news/android-tutorial-how-parse and if finding more than 1 field in a json object see this to add multiple object to listview http://www.josecgomez.com/2010/05/03/android-putting-custom-objects-in-listview/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at these two tutorials, In these Json object are displayed in Custom ListView, I think this is what you needed,

[Android Putting Custom Objects in ListView](http://www.josecgomez.com/2010/05/03/android-putting-custom-objects-in-listview/)

[Populate Listview from JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277154/populate-listview-from-json/8113337#8113337)

Comment: Frankenstein and user370305 thanks for ur suggestions... It will help me alot.. Thank u very much...

Comment: Second link is expired.

Comment: While this answer may theoretically answer the question, [it is better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

For simple example no need of custom list view. you can work with simple list view.

- Parse the JSON data retrieve the data
- store them in a list and pass that list as an argument to the adapter
- set the adapter to the list view.

Answer (score 0):

You will need custom list adapter,  and possibly  custom list entry.

Assuming you have already parsed your JSON and have JSON Array, 
this adapter will have to:
  - provide amoubnt of entries in JSON arary
  - create and populate entry views on demand for certain list entry identified by position. Keep in mind, that list entries are reusable ( and they should be reused to reduce amount of object alloaction)

If there is a lot of data  in JSON, better approach would be to use GSON pull parser and some databinding , to create java objects  istead of built in JSON parser