# ArrayAdapter for JSONArray?

Tags: android, json, wordpress, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to create an ArrayAdapter for a custom JSONArray.
I didn't find any tutorials I could use.
The app is getting data from WordPress. It is getting all the posts, the class gets filled, but I don't know how to display the class into a list.
It is declared as `private Posts[] mPosts;` So the array of posts get's parsed into an array of Posts objects;
I have a List declared in my `activity_main`, I have a `row.xml` for the different objects. All that's left is the arrayadapter, which I can't seem to do.
I can post MainActivity and XML files, but the post will be too long.

Posts.class

```
public class Posts {

private String mId;
private String mDate;
private String mTitle;
private String mContent;
private String mCategories;


public String getId() {
    return mId;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    mId = id;
}

public String getDate() {
    return mDate;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    mDate = date;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return mTitle;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    mTitle = title;
}

public String getContent() {
    return mContent;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    mContent = content;
}

public String getCategories() {
    return mCategories;
}

public void setCategories(String categories) {
    mCategories = categories;
}
```

Comment: use [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/2dd4d17a93caf02ff696533e82f952b0) generic adapter

Comment: Just create Adapter class and extend with ArrayAdapter<>.  And override GetView() method

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayAdapter` cannot adapt a `JSONArray`, as `JSONArray` is not a Java array (`[]` notation) and does not implement the `java.util.List` interface.

You are welcome to create [a subclass of `BaseAdapter` that handles `JSONArray`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879592/how-to-load-data-to-custom-listview-from-json-array).

Comment: I did see that question and I tried to mimick it, but because my Array is full of custom JSONObjects, I couldn't get the parameters of my Posts.class due to it not being JSONObject.getString(), I need to do Posts.getTitle(); and I couldn't move posts to the Adapter class.

Comment: @lakimens: Either convert your `JSONArray` into an `ArrayList<Posts>` and use `ArrayAdapter`, or delete `Posts` and use the `JSONArray` directly with a custom `BaseAdapter`. Or, better yet, use a better JSON parser (e.g., Gson), so you do not have a `JSONArray` in the first place.

Comment: My bad, I don't have a JSONArray, I have an array of JSONObjects(Posts.class), it's a java array(mPosts[]), not a JSONArray, I still haven't made the adapter though.