# How to convert JSON response to string in Android?

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JSON Array iteration in Android/Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408985/json-array-iteration-in-android-java)

I am developing an app where i am using the following [JSONWeb Services Code](http://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient/). Everything is working good and getting response as JSON Array. I am not having any idea how to convert JSON Array to string. The response i am getting is in the following pattern..

Json Respone

```
[
{
     "Id":101,
     "Movie":"xxxxx",
     "Available":
        [             
            {
              "date":"31-08-2012",
              "timings":
                  [
                   "10:15",
                   "10:30",
                   "10:40"
                   ]
            },
            {
                "date":"1-09-2012",
                "timings":
                    [
                     "10:15",
                     "10:30",
                     "10:40"
                     ]
            }
        ]
}
]
```

This is the response i am getting. Can anyone suggest me how to convert the following Json Response to string in android and i want to display that data in listview in android native.

Comment: Converting to String or Object?

Comment: Your response from web service is an String. Is your problem converting that string to Object?

Comment: I think your question was not made properly. You want to know how to display JSON data in a listview, right?

Comment: -1 for lack of search http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408985/json-array-iteration-in-android-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277154/populate-listview-from-json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at this sample and convert per your need

ps: a json array is one which starts with [ and ends with ]
a json object starts with{ and ends with } so in your case available is a json array and its 1 st object contains a json string date and another json array timings

```
JSONArray ja =jso.getJSONArray("Available");





            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jobj=ja.getJSONObject(i);
                xyz[i]=jobj.getString("date");
                abcd[i]=jobj.getJSONArray("timings").tostring;


            }


            }
```

edit:

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
   JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser(); 
   JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
   try { for (int i=0; i< json.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject details = json.getJSONObject(i);
    String id = details.getString("Id");
    String name = details.getString("Name");
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
   map.put(TAG_ID, id); map.put(TAG_NAME, name);


    contactList.add(map)
    JSONArray ja=details.getJSONArray("Available");

        for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jobj=ja.getJSONObject(i);
           String a =jobj.getString("date");
          String b   =jobj.getJSONArray("timings").tostring;
    HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
   map2.put("a", a); map2.put("b", b);
    contactList.add(map2)

        }

     }
```

Comment: here as per my response "Available is an array which consists of objects, date & timings. Here again timings is an array of objects. " How to convert the following. Getting confusion with that. Can you please help me with this....

Comment: can you pls specify the reason of this down vote

Comment: i am not the one down voted it even added a vote for your answer.........

Comment: sorry i didnt mean that you down voted again you can reffer w3schools for a better understanding of json

Comment: so here the whole json is an array and its 1 st object contains another array(availability) and two strings i hope you can coustomize as per your need from there on

Comment: after a long search i added the following code "  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
try {
for (int i=0; i< json.length(); i++)
{    
JSONObject details = json.getJSONObject(i);
String id = details.getString("Id");
String name = details.getString("Name");
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put(TAG_ID, id);
map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
contactList.add(map);" I am not getting how to add "AVAILABLE array". can you help me...

Comment: k from there you shoyld add JSONArray ja=details.getJSONArray("availability"); and continue the steps you followed for getting string

Comment: As per your code after converting to string, i am getting "timings" output as in the following manner "["10:15","10:30","10:40"]". How to get individually timings... like i want each time into separate string. String a = "10:15". String b = "10:30".. like this.....

Comment: you can create another loop and extract those strings  String b   =jobj.getJSONArray("timings").tostring;
change to  JSONArray baaa   =jobj.getJSONArray("timings"); for (int i = 0; i < baa.length(); i++) {  String b=ja.getJSONObject(i).tostring;} and add to map

Answer (score 1):

Check the [link](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database)

It shows the full example to communicate with the server and get response in Json format.

Though in this PHP,MySql is used but I guess the json response you get is same for all languages.