# Fragment, JSON, ListView

Tags: java, php, android, android-listview

I have a class that extends Fragment.

At onCreateView I must request a JSON from a PHP file and put some columns in a listview in a layout (fragment_events).

I've already done the HTTP request and I have my JSON file ready, now what can I do to populate my listview?

I have one class extend Fragment, I can't do for example new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.main in Fragment!!

Comment: [Link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277154/populate-listview-from-json) [Link 2](http://bobbyprabowo.wordpress.com/2010/11/25/android-json-processing-using-gson-and-display-in-on-a-listview/) [Link3 will definitely helps you](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/)

Comment: ok, perfect, but I have one class extend Fragment, I can't do for example new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.main in Fragment!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try ListFragment class, It will help you to do implement listview